# Grouping of data based on week using apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, nosql-aggregation

I am new bee to spark, I have around 15 TB data in mongo

```
ApplicationName  Name        IPCategory Success   Fail  CreatedDate
  abc            a.com        cd          3      1      25-12-2015 00:00:00
  def            d.com        ty          2      2      25-12-2015 01:20:00
  abc            b.com        cd          5      0      01-01-2015 06:40:40
```

I am looking for based on ApplicationName, groupby (Name,IpCategory) for one week data.I am able to fetch data from mongo and save output to mongo. I am working on it using java.

NOTE:- From one month data I need only last week. It should be groupby(Name,IPCategory).

Comment: Please try to elaborate a little. It is not clear what exactly you need or what kind of problems you've encountered.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am guessing from the title that you want to group records by CreatedDate, by calendar weeks. Is that right? If so, maybe you can edit your question to say that specifically.

Comment: I updated query. Let me know if its still unclear.